# Unable to resolve service for type 'GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Repository.IProductRepository'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, automapper

In my .NET 6 application, I get the following error: Unable to resolve service for type 'GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Repository.IProductRepository' while attempting to activate 'GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Controllers.ProductController'

My ProductController :

```
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository _repository;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductVO>>> FindAll()
        {
            var products = await _repository.FindAll();
            return Ok(products);
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ProductVO>> FindById(long id)
        {
            var product = await _repository.FindById(id);
            if (product == null) return NotFound();
            return Ok(product);
        }

    }
```

My program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SqlServerContext> (option =>
        option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
//builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

Even with the addSocped the error persists, somebody could help me?

Comment: Show the constructor for your repository. Also look carefully at the error it gives; it often explains why.

Comment: public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private readonly SqlServerContext _context;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public ProductRepository(SqlServerContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

Comment: And when I added the Startup class to my solution, it worked. but I want to know why DI doesn't just work with program.cs

Comment: What about namespaces? Don't you accidentally have a different IProductRepository in another namespace?

Comment: +1 on checking the namespace. A common trip-up is not noticing the intellisense helpers selecting to end up creating a new IProductRepository interface/class where you expect it to add a `using` statement. Most commonly this happens when referencing an interface in an assembly/project that isn't referenced.

Comment: @SauloTorres could you show the whole cs files with using sections and global using section? It will be easier to find any namespace issues

Comment: usings of mt program.cs:`using AutoMapper;
using GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Config;
using GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Model.Context;
using GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Repository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: namespace of controller: `using GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Data.ValueObjects;
using GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GeekShopping.ProductAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
       ...`

Comment: Where do I find the global usings?

Comment: @SauloTorres docs for global usings can e found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier

Comment: It seems to me you have everything ok with namespaces. And it looks like you are using asp.net core minimal api in your application. Are you sure you aren't doing something weird with application builder? Could you show the whole application? github or something like this?

Comment: @zetroot https://github.com/SauloTorres/GeekShopping

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your dependencies **after** building application with DI-container and running it.
Some code from your repo:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build(); // <-- after this line your DI-container is built and you can't register anything new in it

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/*
 * blah blah some code goes here
 */
app.MapControllers();

app.Run(); // <-- here you run your application and the further execution is blocked until your application finished its lifecycle

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SqlServerContext> (option =>
        option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
// ^^^^^^ this code won't be executed before application starts!! ^^^^^^
// It is written after app.Run() and will be executed after app.Run() is exited.
```

The solution is simple - just register all your dependencies **before** you build your DI and **before** you start your application. Something like this should work:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SqlServerContext> (option =>
        option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
// register all your other dependencies here
var app = builder.Build(); // <-- register before this line!!!

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/*
 * blah blah some code goes here
 */
app.MapControllers();

app.Run(); 
// here you can only do some clean-up job
```